# JavaScript Time Tracker Tool

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet, time-tracking

I'm trying to build a web-based task time-tracker.

The tracker will be a stopwatch with the following fields:

1-Team Name  (Drop Down field)
2-Task Name  (Drop Down field)
3-Task Count (Manual Entry)
4-Start Time (Triggered when turning on stopwatch)
5-Stop Time  (Triggered when turning off stopwatch)
6-Time Elapsed (Difference between start/stop time)
7-Submit Button (Manual Click)

The functionality will work as follows:
-A user will log the task/processor name and then click start on the stopwatch.
-The start time will be recorded in the start time field
-The user will perform a task a number of times
-The user will click the stopwatch again when done with the work they set out to complete
-The end time field will be automatically recorded when the stopwatch is paused
-The time elapsed will be calculated between the start and stop time
-The user will enter in the number of tasks they completed in the task count field
-The user will click submit
-When the submit button is clicked, all data in the fields above will be sent to a spreadsheet/storage location.

The stopwatch is intended to be used by several users on multiple machines.

How can I have this link to a data storage location where a complete list of all submitted data can be found? I need to know if the spreadsheet linking is a capability that can be web based?

Comment: For the people who aren't familiar with [tag:kronos-workforce-central], can you mention it a bit in your post body, and how it relates to your question? It might help prevent unrelated answers where people don't notice that tag.

Comment: I removed it, sorry for the confusion